# Getting XML body - Deserialization errors on a call to a soap webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, .net-3.5

I've got a problem with my soapwebservice and a new C# client I'm writing for it. The serverside is of modern standards .NET Framework wise  while the client only has .NET 3.5.

Whenever I'm trying to return a string from the webapplication I get the error:

> "Fehler beim Deserialisieren des Textkörpers der Antwortnachricht für Vorgang \"MyMethod\"." with the einner exception: "Fehler im XML-Dokument (1,40286)."
>   Translated: A serialization error for the server response with an XML-Document error.

Now what is more confusing for me is:

- Whenever I instead of returning the text throw an Exception in the Webmethod (Example: throw new ArgumentException ), I get NO serialization error.
- When a java client consumes this web service.....I get no error at all from that client.

Clientcode:

```
public void MyMethod (bool _IsInDebugMode, MyWebMethodRef.MyProxySoapClient myclient)
{
    BasicHttpSecurityMode secMode = (_IsInDebugMode) ? BasicHttpSecurityMode.None : BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
    BasicHttpBinding wsBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(secMode);

    wsBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
    wsBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    wsBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    wsBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
    wsBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);

    string ret = myclient.myMethod(Convert.ToBase64String("Test"));
}
```

Servercode:

```
public class MyProxy : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public MyProxyHeader header;

    [WebMethod]
    [SoapHeader("header")]
    public string myMethod(string mytext)
    {

        return Convert.ToBase64String("blahblubb");
    }
}
```

Now I'm quite a bit confused there and my question is: What could cause this deserialization error and how to eliminate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally foujnd out what was the cause. Still though  I'm a bit baffled as to WHY it is so, without any word of it standing anywhere.

In essence: As soon as I updated the clients .NET Framework to 4.6 it started working.
Which looks like that the newest .NET Frameworks build the xml strings differently than the 3.5 .NET Framework, which means that they are not that far downward compatible!